# A method to find the difference between two dates

Tags: java

My method works, as I only want to know the difference in years, my problem is that I am so inefficient in doing this. I have a feeling there is a much more simple and aesthetically pleasing way to write the method.

Edit: I have to write my own method. I also prefer to not go out of my way and use advanced things, something within the range of a first year programmer.

```
public int differenceInYears(MyDate comparedDate) {
        int difference = 0;
        if (this.year > comparedDate.year) {
            if (this.month > comparedDate.month) {
                difference = this.year - comparedDate.year;
            }
            else if (this.month == comparedDate.month) {
                if (this.day >= comparedDate.day) {
                    difference = this.year - comparedDate.year;
                }
                else {
                    difference = this.year - comparedDate.year - 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                difference = this.year - comparedDate.year - 1;
            }
        }
        if (comparedDate.year > this.year) {
            if (comparedDate.month > this.month) {
                difference = comparedDate.year - this.year;
            }
            else if (comparedDate.month == this.month) {
                if (comparedDate.day >= this.day) {
                    difference = comparedDate.year - this.year;
                }
                else {
                    difference = comparedDate.year - this.year - 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                difference = comparedDate.year - this.year - 1;
            }
        }
        return difference;
    }
```

I will add the `MyDate` class below for context:

```
public class MyDate {

    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;

    public MyDate(int day, int montd, int year) {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = montd;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.day + "." + this.month + "." + this.year;
    }

    public boolean earlier(MyDate compared) {
        if (this.year < compared.year) {
            return true;
        }

        if (this.year == compared.year && this.month < compared.month) {
            return true;
        }

        if (this.year == compared.year && this.month == compared.month
                && this.day < compared.day) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating the difference between two Java date instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Comment: Do you need to write this method yourself? It'd be much better to use a built-in library call.

Comment: It's a `MyDate` object. He wrote it himself I think

Comment: There are a lot of libraries that you can use for archiving this. And Even Mathematic Formulas for calculating

Comment: Yes, indeed I do.

Comment: How about simple: `return this.year - comparedDate.year;`?

Comment: Can you show the `MyDate` class plz?

Comment: @Roel it has to consider the month and the day.

Comment: Why? The method's name is `differenceInYears` and the return type is an integer. Edit: I get it now =D

Comment: If you asked it the difference between December 31st 2016 and January 1st 2017 would you want it to give you a year? I assume not.

Comment: @Roel, it's part of the exercise I'm supposed to adapt with what it gives me, with that being said I passed the exercise  I'm just looking for better ways.

Comment: @zack, it should only return the difference in years nothing more, but it has to be atleast 365 days

Comment: My point was directed to Roel, not you.

Comment: using Math.abs() can clean up half of that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will presume that your method works correctly. How can it be improved? The first thing you can do is eliminate all of the repeated `this.year - comparedDate.year` and `comparedDate.year - this.year` calculations. You do them no matter what, so let's put them at the top of their respective `if` blocks.

```
public int differenceInYears(MyDate comparedDate) {
    int difference;

    if (this.year > comparedDate.year) {
        difference = this.year - comparedDate.year;

        if (this.month > comparedDate.month) {
        }
        else if (this.month == comparedDate.month) {
            if (this.day >= comparedDate.day) {
            }
            else {
                difference -= 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            difference -= 1;
        }
    }
    if (comparedDate.year > this.year) {
        difference = comparedDate.year - this.year;

        if (comparedDate.month > this.month) {
        }
        else if (comparedDate.month == this.month) {
            if (comparedDate.day >= this.day) {
            }
            else {
                difference -= 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            difference -= 1;
        }
    }

    return difference;
}
```

Next, let's get rid of those empty branches.

```
public int differenceInYears(MyDate comparedDate) {
    int difference;

    if (this.year > comparedDate.year) {
        difference = this.year - comparedDate.year;

        if (this.month == comparedDate.month) {
            if (this.day < comparedDate.day) {
                difference -= 1;
            }
        }
        else if (this.month < comparedDate.month) {
            difference -= 1;
        }
    }
    if (comparedDate.year > this.year) {
        difference = comparedDate.year - this.year;

        if (comparedDate.month == this.month) {
            if (comparedDate.day < this.day) {
                difference -= 1;
            }
        }
        else if (comparedDate.month < this.month) {
            difference -= 1;
        }
    }

    return difference;
}
```

Now let's see if we can't squeeze together some of the conditions with `&&` and `||`.

```
public int differenceInYears(MyDate comparedDate) {
    int difference;

    if (this.year > comparedDate.year) {
        difference = this.year - comparedDate.year;

        if (this.month == comparedDate.month && this.day < comparedDate.day ||
            this.month < comparedDate.month)
        {
            difference -= 1;
        }
    }
    if (comparedDate.year > this.year) {
        difference = comparedDate.year - this.year;

        if (comparedDate.month == this.month && comparedDate.day < this.day ||
            comparedDate.month < this.month)
        {
            difference -= 1;
        }
    }

    return difference;
}
```

Those two blocks look awfully similar, don't they? We could combine them by conditionally swapping `this` and `comparedDate`. Let `a` and `b` be the earlier and later date, respectively.

```
public int differenceInYears(MyDate comparedDate) {
    MyDate a = (this.year < comparedDate.year) ? this : comparedDate;
    MyDate b = (this.year < comparedDate.year) ? comparedDate : this;

    int difference = b.year - a.year;

    if (a.year < b.year) {
        if (a.month == b.month && a.day < b.day ||
            a.month < b.month)
        {
            difference -= 1;
        }
    }

    return difference;
}
```

And one final squeeze.

```
public int differenceInYears(MyDate comparedDate) {
    MyDate a = (this.year < comparedDate.year) ? this : comparedDate;
    MyDate b = (this.year < comparedDate.year) ? comparedDate : this;

    int difference = b.year - a.year;

    if (a.year < b.year &&
       (a.month == b.month && a.day < b.day ||
        a.month < b.month))
    {
        difference -= 1;
    }

    return difference;
}
```

Comment: Very well explained!

Answer (score 1):

Okay so after some consideration, I think this may look a bit nicer:

```
public int differenceInYears(MyDate comparedDate){
    //Calculate days total
    long daysTotalThisDate = this.year * 365 + this.month * 30 + this.day;
    long daysTotalComparedDate = comparedDate.year * 365 + comparedDate.month * 30 + comparedDate.day;

    //Get absolute value
    long differenceInDays = daysTotalThisDate - daysTotalComparedDate;
    if (differenceInDays < 0){
        differenceInDays *= -1;
    }

    //the (int) cast will always round down, so anything under 365 will be 0
    return (int) differenceInDays / 365;
}
```

This does NOT take into account leap years.

Before people think my calculation of `daysTotal...` is wrong. You are correct. But I did it wrong for both calculations, so the end result is still ok considering we only need to calculate difference in year, not days.

Comment: I know the calculation isn't correct, but the end result still is. since we're returning an int: whether we return 30/365 or 29/365. In both cases 0 is returned.

Comment: It's sheerly by coincidence that this can work. This answer is incomplete without explaining the nuances. Specifically it works because the average number of days for a month(30.417) is bigger than the longest month(31) subtract 1(30). If this fact weren't true you would not be able to do this.

Comment: I see it now. You are correct indeed. Especially when the years are more apart. Thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: Also using the Math.abs function cleans this up a fair bit

Comment: Yes but I wasn't sure he wanted or could use this

Answer (score 0):

The key point here is: sometimes "complex" computations are required.

In that sense: do not worry about being inefficient. You should spend your time on trying to write really readable code; very much like the answer from John is guiding you. In general, you would be looking towards principles as the "[single layer of abstraction](https://dzone.com/articles/the-single-level-of-abstraction-principle)" principle for example; to avoid having such lengthy if/else cascades.

The other key point: such assignments are **perfect** for unit testing. In other words: you should start with writing little testcases that simply call your method with various (pre-selected) input dates; to then check that the expected result is returned.

In other words:

You first focus on writing a lot of testcases that you can you to **determine** that your implementation is correct ... because that enables you to *refactor* your code without being afraid of *breaking* it.

Using JUnit is as easy as:

```
@Test
public testDifferenceIs0 {
  MyDate thisYear = new MyDate(1,1,2017);
  MyDate thisYearToo = new MyDate(1,1,2017);
  assertThat(thisYear.differenceInYears(thisYearToo), is(0));
}
```

for example.